# Inter-Elastic Beanstalk communication within the same VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

**I have two beanstalk applications which are on the same VPC. How do I call API on one from the other without going over the internet?**

**More context:** The EC2's in both my beanstalk applications spans across 2 AZ's, and they reside in public subnets too. The Beanstalk URL is publicly accessible. So when I call one beanstalk from the other, how do I know for sure that the connection is not going over the internet (or leaving my VPC) for inter-beanstalk communication? Both ELB's in my beanstalks are public facing. DNS resolution alone would require the application on one beanstalk (with the endpoint URL of other beanstalk hardcoded in it) to go out to the internet right?

**Note:** I cannot use the **internal ELB** option as the APIs will be accessed from the internet as well. But when they try and access other API's (on their own beanstalk) within the same VPC, I want to make sure the communication is internal to the VPC.

**I want my inter-beanstalk communication within my VPC to stay within my VPC without going out to the internet. Any suggestions?**

Comment: Do you use Single Instance o LB ?